# Configuring InvalidModelStateResponseFactory with Minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, minimal-apis

In ASP.NET Core with controllers I was able to customize the error response when a model binding error ocurred by adding the following in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
    {
        var errors = actionContext.ModelState
            .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
            .Select(e => new
            {
                Name = e.Key,
                Message = e.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage
            }).ToArray();

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);
    };
});
```

This doesn't seem to be working with minimal API. How can I achieve the same results with Minimal API?

Answer (score 2):

Minimal api does not support `Model Binding`, So you can't use `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` in Minimal api.

**Microsoft official documents are as follows**

> No support for model binding, i.e. IModelBinderProvider,   IModelBinder. Support can be added with a custom binding shim.

> No
> support for binding from forms. This includes binding IFormFile. We
> plan to add support for IFormFile in the future.

You can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#differences-between-minimal-apis-and-apis-with-controllers) to learn more details about the different between `minimal api and controller api`

Comment: If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Thanks.

Comment: My question was how can I achieve the same result in minimal API. This was helpful in understanding why model binding doesn't work in minimal APi, but doesn't solve the issue.